# Mark New Nodes in Views via Template

Tags: theming

I have a portfolio view that displays all items in the portfolio. The fields are set via template so I do not have access to the fields area in views to select the parameter there, I have to do it within my node template.

The issue is I can't figure out what code to stick in there to display the "New" tag if the visitor has not yet viewed the node.

This is the code I have in the template:

```
<div class="portfolio-name">
  <h3><a href="<?php print $node_url?>"><?php print $title;?></a></h3>           
  <span><?php print strip_tags(render($content['field_portfolio_categories'])); ?></span>
  <span><!-- PUT **NEW** FLAG HERE --></span>
</div>
```

I have googled and found the info here (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_mark/7) but I just can't figure out how to translate it to what code I put in my actual template file to make it happen.

Thank you so much for your help.

---

Thank you for your answer!  I am primarily a themer and php just is not my strong suit.

I have changed my code to be:

```
<div class="portfolio-name">
  <h3><a href="<?php print $node_url?>"><?php print $title;?></a></h3>
  <span><?php print strip_tags(render($content['field_portfolio_categories'])); ?>   </span>
  <?php
    if (node_last_viewed($node->nid) > 0) {
       print '<span>' .  theme('mark', array('type' => MARK_NEW)) . '</span>';
    }
  ?>             
</div>
```

This code displays the "new" text, but only if I am logged in as the administrator and it displays on all items, not just ones I have not visited yet.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php print theme('mark', array('type' => node_mark($node->nid, $node->changed))); ?>
```

this is how it is done on the content overview page. give it a try, it will display read for anonymous users' - probably ..,

here's the code from node_mark, where node_last_viewed is used:

```
function node_mark($nid, $timestamp) {
  global $user;
  $cache = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());

  if (!$user->uid) {
    return MARK_READ;
  }
  if (!isset($cache[$nid])) {
    $cache[$nid] = node_last_viewed($nid);
  }
  if ($cache[$nid] == 0 && $timestamp > NODE_NEW_LIMIT) {
    return MARK_NEW;
  }
  elseif ($timestamp > $cache[$nid] && $timestamp > NODE_NEW_LIMIT) {
    return MARK_UPDATED;
  }
  return MARK_READ;
}
```

so for you maybe this could be used (statistics module needs to be enabled)

```
 <?php
      if (node_last_viewed($node->nid) == 0) {
        print '<span>' .  theme('mark', array('type' => MARK_NEW)) . '</span>';
      }
```

**best to call this theme function (and any logic) in the preprocess method, and use a variable in the template ..**

Comment: I edited my question above.

Comment: Ok, I now get the "new" text, but only if I am logged in as an admin and it is showing new for all items, even if I have visited the node or not.  Any ideas?

Comment: this only works for logged in users, and it did not work because i did the if-check wrong .. node_last_viewed returns a timestamp or 0 .. - i edited the code above

Comment: if you need anonymous hits counted - give [nodeviewcount](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) a try